# Is "presently present" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, error

While reading a documentation, I came across the following sentence

> The new class library will contain all the business logic **presently present** in the project ABC.

Is "presently present" correct? Can this sentence be rephrased any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Presently present" is technically correct but isn't very good wording.  It will cause some readers to pause to ponder the wording and might even cause a bit of confusion.

I would say "**currently present**".